# pg8000 postgres connection issues from python

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pg8000

I'm having trouble connecting to a db on a new system. The version of Python is the same. Here is the connection string for the DB that is there and you'll see the error message change, but I cannot work out why when the connection string is correct I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pg8000/__init__.py", line 148, in connect
    user, host, unix_sock, port, database, password, socket_timeout, ssl)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 1157, in __init__
    raise exc_info()[1]
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Here is my connection string when correct:

```
conn = DBAPI.connect(host='sql2', user='XXX', password='XX', database='XX', socket_timeout=100, port=5432)
```

and when I change to something incorrect:

```
conn = DBAPI.connect(host='sql2', user='XXX', password='XX', database='XX', socket_timeout=100, port=100)
```

and the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/opt/Centos5.8/python-2.7.4_scipy0.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pg8000/__init__.py", line 148, in connect
    user, host, unix_sock, port, database, password, socket_timeout, ssl)
  File "/mnt/opt/Centos5.8/python-2.7.4_scipy0.13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pg8000/core.py", line 854, in __init__
    raise InterfaceError("communication error", exc_info()[1])
pg8000.errors.InterfaceError: ('communication error', error(111, 'Connection refused'))
```

I cannot figure out where this error message is coming from - it seems bizzare. I've tried:

wrapping string in `str()`
putting `u'ss'`
removing port, adding socket-timeout etc etc.

When I looked in the core.py code from pg8000 it appears that this comes from an authentication error if you chase it through. I think this error (int and str) might be eclipsing the authentication error.

## Message codes

AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST = b("R")

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the `socket_timeout` and `port` values in `str()` individually?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense, need socket_timeout and port as integer - I tried wrapping. host=str(dbsettings['host']), user=str(dbsettings['user']), password=str(dbsettings['password']), database=str(dbsettings['database']), port=dbsettings['port'], ssl=dbsettings['ssl']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [bug in pg8000](https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000/pull/40). It was [fixed in pg8000-1.9.11](https://web.archive.org/web/20180211070008/https://pythonhosted.org//pg8000/release_notes.html#version-1-9-11-2014-07-20). The bug is an error in reporting the error that pg8000 encountered while trying to authenticate against the database.

Comment: I changed to the updated code and now I get a proper error: pg8000.errors.InterfaceError: Authentication method 3 not supported by pg8000.

Comment: Method 3 is plain text password authentication. I think pg8000 should support it, so I've created a feature request at https://github.com/mfenniak/pg8000/issues/52.